# How to measure Earth’s magnetic field?

Tags: measurement-devices

I want to measure [Earth’s magnetic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field). I want to chart the strength of these fields to observe how they change daily, and compare those details to  global records. My question is **what kind of meter/device** I should buy and where to buy it?

During my research I think I should buy a [deutrometer](http://ritmindustry.com/catalog/measuring-instruments-for-electrostatic-fields/electrical-field-measuring-device-portable/)  but I am not sure. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The device you cited is spendy; if your budget does not permit acquiring it, there are alternatives.

You could get an iPhone and the [xSensor](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xsensor/id345145166) app cited in this [Wired article](https://www.wired.com/2014/01/measure-magnetic-field/), or an Android phone with three-axis magnetic sensors (note: Not all Android phones do have three-axis magnetic sensors) and an app like [Physics Toolbox Magnetometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrystianvieyra.android.physicstoolboxmagnetometer&hl=en_US) as those apps measure the ambient magnetic field on all three axes. Then, log the results periodically.

I'd also suggest determining the accuracy of those historical records as a guide to how precise the measuring instrument must be. If the records you use as a baseline are not very accurate, spending a lot of money on a very precise meter may not be very useful.

The [ARRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Radio_Relay_League) does confirm [terrestial magnetic fields change frequently, BTW](http://www.arrl.org/the-sun-the-earth-the-ionosphere).